# the sentence "if it so please the gods"

Tags: grammar

I saw a sentence in a book that goes like this: "*If it so please the gods, so be it*".

Why "please" is used instead of "pleases"? I suppose, that's some archaic stylization, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does this sentence have too many subjunctives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148251/does-this-sentence-have-too-many-subjunctives) ('Does this sentence have too many subjunctives?

_If it please the king, let it be decreed that they be destroyed, and I will pay 10,000 talents of silver into the hands of those who have charge of the king's business_ ....') // Or [What is the grammar behind _thanks be to God_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84447/what-is-the-grammar-behind-thanks-be-to-god/84460#84460)

Comment: Yes, that's some archaic stylization. _If it please `X`_ is a fixed phrase with archaic syntax, sometimes called "subjunctive", which uses an infinitive form instead of a present tense form in certain phrases.  In the US, the most common use is the legal phrase _If it please the court_, used only in formal judicial proceedings. Nobody talks this way, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: thank you for your great answers!